# How to save details into aray in mongoodb using mongoose and express

Tags: mongodb, express

I want to save some user information in array in mongodb database using mongoose and express. Its not saving any Information. It saves array with empty data. Please help me to solve this.
here is my api.js

```html
router.post('/requests/:id', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body;
    const userId = req.userId;
    User.findById(req.params.id, (error,user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else 
           if (!user) {
               res.status(401).send('user Does not exists')
           } else { 
               user.save({$push: {requests: {
                 _id: userId,
                 Bloodgroup: userData.bloodgroup,
                 City: userData.city
               }}})
              res.status(200).send(user)
           }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

here is my user schema

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema


const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname:{type: String},
    lastname:{type: String},
    email: {type: String,  unique:true},
    phonenumber:{type: Number, unique:true},
    bloodgroup:{type: String},
    gender:{type: String},
    dateofbirth:{type: String},
    city:{type: String},
    imagePath: {type: String},
    username: {type:String,  unique:true}, 
    password:{type: String},
    
    requests: [{
        _id: {type: Object},
        Bloodgroup: {type: String},
        City: {type: String}
    }]
})

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'users')
```

Comment: I don't think [document.save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save) works that way.  Try modifying the document directly and then calling `user.save()`

Comment: please show me code exmaple

Comment: The first example at https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update demponstrates.that